# Netsuite REST API - Set tax registration number on customer record

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

Something which seems so simple is sadly proving a headache, and hoping someone can direct me on what I am doing wrong.

I am using the NetSuite REST API to create a customer and trying to set the TAX REG NUMBER when I fire my request. The request seems to be successful as everything creates successfully, except this one field.

Here's the payload I am using:

```
{
 "isperson": false,
 "companyname":"Homer Simpson LTD",
 "externalId": "Homer-UK3-Simpson-LTD",
 "subsidiary": "4",
 "email": "Simpson@testing.com",
 "phone": "01254354278",
 "taxRegistration": {
     "items": [
         {
            "address": "123 testing this out",
            "refName":"DEFAULT_TAX_001",
            "nexusCountry":{
                "id":"GB",
                "refName": "United Kingdom"
            },  
            "taxRegistrationNumber": "0125448653"
         }
     ]
 },
 "addressBook": {
        "items": [
            {
                "addressBookAddress": {
                    "zip": "RG7 5TT",
                    "city": "London",
                    "addr1": "5000 HELLO Close",
                    "state": "Berkshire",
                    "country": {
                        "id": "GB",
                        "refName": "United Kingdom"
                    },
                    "override": true
                }
                
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I am trying to use the "customer-taxRegistrationCollection" as per the REST API found via: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2023.1/index.html#/definitions/customer-taxRegistrationCollection

Thanks,
Arif

Answer (score 0):

I have logged a very similar call with Netsuite and they've confirmed you must have Suitetax installed for this to work.
This issue has arisen since the installation of 2023.1

Comment: Thanks for your response. It will really help if you could add a link to the issue or ticket